# Does choosing www version as default URL in Google Analytics affect subdomain tracking?

Tags: google-analytics

My website is set to use the www version (www.example.com) as the default URL in Google Analytics. My universal code will appear on both the www pages and on other subdomains (products.example.com). Will Google Analytics properly track traffic on both website pages? Note that I have already set up the referral exclusions and cookie domain to treat visits between the www pages and the subdomains as internal traffic. I just need to know whether using the www version as default URL and using that universal code on all pages will still track traffic on www and subdomains. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default URL setting has no bearing on what is tracked on your site. It's merely a setting for your reports to help remove redundant pages:

> The Default URL field is used to help correct an issue with our website where we can load the same exact page with two different URLs.

Reference: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/09/04/google-analytics-default-page/#what-is-the-default-url

Comment: Will Google Analytics properly track traffic on both the www webpages (www.example.com) and the other subdomain pages (products.example.com) if I use the same code on each?

Comment: GA tracks on whatever pages you have the tracking code on, so if you have it on www and subd's then yes it will be tracked. Make sure you set the cookie domain to auto so that movement across subd's are kept in the same session and also update your referral exclusion list so that there are no self referrals. You can also set up filters in different views to see traffic specific to a subd.